# How to find the number of times a specific element occurs in an Array list in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, bluej

I have written a method with the aim to count the number of times a specific flavour of crisps appears in a snack machine in blueJ

```
public int countPacks(String flavour){

        int n = 0;
        int nrFlavour = 0;
        while( n < packets.size()) {
            if( packets.get(n).equals(flavour)){
                nrFlavour++;
                n++;
            }
            else n++;
        }
        return nrFlavour;
}
```

I have an Arraylist 'packets' which holds PackOfCrisps objects which have a specific flavour. However when I have added say three packets of "salt" flavour crisps and I run this method, inputting "salt" as the flavour, it just returns 0 as though there are no PackOfCrisps objects with flavour "salt".
Sorry if this doesn't make sense. I am very new to Java and I have tried to explain my problem the best I can. :)

Comment: Please provide a **complete** code example that illustrates what you are asking about. We should be able to copy and paste it and then run it as-is. (Well, feel free to leave out import statements, as we can add those quite easily.) When anyone else runs the program you provide, we should get exactly the behavior you are asking about.

Comment: Is `packets` an `ArrayList<String>` or an `ArrayList<PackOfCrisps>` (or some other type)?  If it isn't an `ArrayList<String>`, you won't have `equals` return true.  (I don't know your exact code, but you could try changing `if( packets.get(n).equals(flavour)){` to `if( packets.get(n).flavour.equals(flavour)){`.)

Comment: Show how `packets` is defined and populated.

Comment: it is important to show the code that proves your code is broken. Add the bit where you set up the empty packets list, add "salt" three times, and then call countPacks("salt") so we can see you're right.

Comment: Unrelated, but there's no reason to increment `n` in a conditional; it increments no matter what. In any case, without knowing what data you *actually* have, and what `flavour` *actually* is, it's impossible to help. I'd suggest putting in some debug statements.

Comment: @DaveNewton The OP suggests that `flavor` has the value of `"salt"`, but doesn't give any information about the declaration of `packets`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list `packets` holds `PackOfCrisps` objects, and the method takes a `String` parameter. So the statement `packets.get(n).equals(flavour)` is comparing a `PackOfCrisps` object to a `String`, hence the count variable will never increase.

You need to compare the `flavour` string to the specific field of the object, something like:

```
if(packets.get(n).getFlavour().equals(flavour)){
```

On a side note, you can replace the `while` loop with a simple `for` loop and remove the increment of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in solution to your problem, you can use this [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29)

You can rewrite your `countPacks` method like this :

```
public int countPacks(String flavour){
    return Collections.frequency(packets, flavour);
}
```